# Custom page template works fine on local host but doesn't show up online

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I created a custom page template for a [wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress) theme , as long as I had the theme installed locally page was displayed and showed within it the custom post type associated with it , but when I loaded online theme and I created the page by selecting the template to be used the page content doesn't show up.
It seems that by selecting the page template is not created the page with this template , but creates a page with the content of the index.
this is my page code with the loop that shows a custom_post_type

```
<?php
/*
*Template Name: Partecipanti
*Description : Pagina che raggiude tutte le associazioni partecipanti
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="partecipanti" class="content-container row">
<h2 class="titolo-pagina"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php
$wpquery = new WP_Query(array(
'post_type'      => 'partecipanti',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
 ));
 while ($wpquery->have_posts()): $wpquery->the_post();  
 ?>

    <div class="container-partecipante col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12    visible-xs">

        <?php the_post_thumbnail() ?>
        <h2 class="nome"><?php the_title() ?></h2>
    </div>

    <div class="flip-container container-partecipante col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 hidden-xs" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
        <div class="flipper">
            <div class="front">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail() ?>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
                <h2 class="nome"><?php the_title() ?></h2>
                <a class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" href="<?php  the_permalink(); ?>"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just forgot set Page Template in page's edit? Or it was bugged - try delete template, save page (to auto-remove page template), upload template, set it again and save.

Also check if page template is at all used - for example place plain HTML `test` before `<div id="partecipanti" class="content-container row">` and check if is displayed.

Have you the same WordPress version and plugins installed? Maybe you missed changed setting?

Try with simple page template, for example default full-width - are editor content is displayed?

Or maybe you have the same bug like me with latest WP version - when page is child (have parent page), it's bugged and page template doesn't work + page is outputed as post instead page.

Answer (score 0):

Check file permisions in your theme folder